# Axios not returning data while using asynch await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

This is my axios function

```
const requestAllSubPosts = (sub,epoch,count) => {

  const res = {};
  const sub_url = `https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?subreddit=${sub}&limit=1000&sort=desc&before=${epoch}`;     


 return axios
      .get(sub_url)
      .then(response => {
        const d = response.data.data;

        if(d.length > 0) {
          subFetchEpoch = d[d.length - 1].created_utc;

          subDataArray = subDataArray.concat(d);        
          count++;

          requestAllSubPosts(sub,subFetchEpoch,count)

        }
        else {
           console.log('data-empty');

           res.data = subDataArray;
           res.epoch = subFetchEpoch;

           console.log(res); <-- WORKING
           return  res ; <-- NOT WORKING


        }


      })
      .catch(error => {
        return  error.message 
      });


}
```

I'm using axios in a sort of loop, and fetching data till the response is empty. After that I want to return the appeneded data in the parent function.

This is the parent function. I call on axios and logging the response. But I'm not getting any response

```
async function  fetchAllSubPosts (sub, epoch)  {

      const today = moment(new Date()).valueOf();
      // let ep_a = moment(ep).valueOf()

      let dataArray = [];
      let resp = await requestAllSubPosts(sub, ep, 1) 
      console.log({resp}); <-- NOT WORKING

}
```

Comment: requestAllSubPosts is not a promise

Comment: is promise required for axios?

Comment: Missing  `return` when you recursively call `requestAllSubPosts ()`. Without it the `then()` resolves with `undefined`

Comment: @Sundeep `axios.get()` does return  promise

Comment: What is `reject` in `return reject(error.message)`?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes,  But is is already fulfilled in requestAllSubPosts  function so its no more a promise to be consumed

Comment: @Sundeep It is if it is returned. Your explanation is not clear on that point and is ambiguous

Comment: @Bergi I don't think reject was supposed to be there. I was using promise before. I've edited the code

Answer (score 1):

When you recursively call `requestAllSubPosts()` the `then()` has no `return` and so by default will return `undefined` to the next `then()` or `await` in the chain

You want to `return` the  promise from the recursive call.

Change:

```
 requestAllSubPosts(sub,subFetchEpoch,count)
```

To

```
return  requestAllSubPosts(sub,subFetchEpoch,count)
```

Comment: I've tried return  requestAllSubPosts(sub,subFetchEpoch,count) it is still not working

Comment: I'm fetching all the data and appending it to `res` till the response yields empty. It's just not resolving